# Training validation and accuracy are very high, but testing accuracy is low

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

The training accuracy and validation accuracy of my model is extremely high.

```
...
Epoch 4/5
457/457 [==============================] - 4s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0237 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 0.0036 - val_accuracy: 0.9993
Epoch 5/5
457/457 [==============================] - 4s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0166 - accuracy: 0.9941 - val_loss: 0.0028 - val_accuracy: 0.9994
```

However, upon testing, the accuracy is atrocious:

[image: normalized confusion matrix]

(for high accuracy there would be a green diagonal from top-left to bottom-right)

I am not sure why this is, given the high accuracy and low loss of both the training and validation set. If the model was overfitting, then either the validation loss or accuracy should be deviating from the training loss or accuracy, but it is not.
Here are my data generators:

```py
train_datagen = DataGenerator(
    partition["train"], 
    labels, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    **params
)
val_datagen = DataGenerator(
    partition["val"],
    labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    **params
)
test_datagen = DataGenerator(
    partition["test"],
    labels,
    batch_size=1,
    **params
)
```

Note that since my data takes the form of a npy array on a .npy file, I followed [this post](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) to create a custom datagenerator class.

Here is my training process:

```
history = model.fit(
    train_datagen,
    epochs = 5,
    steps_per_epoch = len(train_datagen),
    validation_data = val_datagen,
    validation_steps = len(val_datagen),
    shuffle = False,
    callbacks = callback,
    use_multiprocessing = True,
    workers = 4
)
```

Here you can see how I partitioned my data:

```py
print(len(partition["train"]))
print(len(partition["val"]))
print(len(partition["test"]))
print(len(partition["train"]) + len(partition["val"]) + len(partition["test"]))
print(good, ok, bad)
# good: 0, ok: 1, bad: 2
```

```
29249
8342
4144
41735
18152 12665 10918
```

I also confirmed that there is no overlap between any of the sets:

```py
print(bool(set(partition["train"]) & set(partition["val"])))
print(bool(set(partition["test"]) & set(partition["val"])))
print(bool(set(partition["train"]) & set(partition["test"])))
```

```
False
False
False
```

Can someone please help me figure out where I went wrong? I'm not sure how it's possible to get such high testing and validation accuracy, but have a terrible testing rate. i have hosted my full code on and files on [Github](https://github.com/4a454646/StridedTransformer-Pose3D).

Comment: Do you know what is Overfitting?

Comment: Yes, but that usually applies if there is high training accuracy but low validation. In my case, both training and validation accuracy are high.

Comment: No, it applies to any disjoint dataset. There are no guarantees to test set performance.

Comment: Could you please explain how I should go about avoiding this overfitting, and what makes my dataset 'disjoint'? I just trained the model with 3 Dropout layers of 80% and got the same results (good accuracy and loss for both training and validation)

Comment: No, not really, overfitting is not a programming problem, it is not something you can solve with some code.

Comment: Then can you explain what is causing my overfitting and how you would go about trying toi solve this problem if you were doing it? Right now you're just telling me that I've done something wrong and then not giving me any help or even ideas how to start fixing it.

Comment: No, that is because you are asking about machine learning methodology which is not a programming issue and is off-topic in this site.

Comment: I posted on Stack Overflow because there is a specific 'machine-learning' tag with over 45,000 questions and I figured that there was something wrong with my code that was causing this. If you say that it is overfitting only, with the implication that my code is fine, I will ask on both Data Science and AI Stack Exchange and you can join me over there and actually help me, since then they will be 'on-topic'.

Comment: You should read the description of the tag https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info , and you should really know that overfitting is not something people can explain why, it is a research problem, your whole attitude to the problem is wrong.

Comment: @JeffChen how your dataset looks like? Is it the proportion of the classes somewhat simular or is it a imbalanced classification problem? When you generate the sets do they have the same proportion of each class?

Answer (score 1):

OK after a few hours of debugging I have found the issue.
[image: normalized confusion matrix]

My neural net successfully reached >99% accuracy on the testing dataset, as was reflected in the training and validation sets. Only 1 wrong prediction was made out of 4144.

The problem was that **I had shuffle turned on for the test dataset**, so when comparing to the non-shuffled list of correct classes that was generated at the start, the results were completely random.